# cpp Abstract class

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I am getting an error

> error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'myClass'

I have made made up a small sample to demonstrate my error.
Below is the code. (includes and #ifndef stuff is not included)

> person.h

```
class Person{
    public:
            virtual std::string getRole() = 0;
};
```

> employee.h

```
class Employee:public Person{
    std::string getRole();
};
```

> workplace.h

```
class Workplace{
    public:
            void  setPeople(std::vector<Person> p);

    private:
            std::vector<Person> people;
};
```

> workplace.cpp

```
void Workplace::setPeople(std::vector<Person> p){
    people = p;
}
```

> employee.cpp

```
std::string Employee::getRole(){
    return "Generic Employee";
}
```

The error I am getting from this example is:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:80: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Person’
>   person.h:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Person’:
>   person.h:9: note:       virtual std::string Person::getRole()

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [*Object slicing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: you cannot have `vector<Person>` (`myClass` in your original error message)